# Google App Engine Standard Env w/ Python 3 & Flask: High latency for (non-)POST requests

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, latency

I'm having a weird problem with calls to my app engine: They show a rather high latency for calls that get identified in the Trace (of the Google Cloud Console) as neither GET nor POST, please see screenshot.

[image]
The calls are made to my `/api` and they all originate from Python code on different normal web servers as well as Travic CI, which show similar latency behavior.

The method used to make the calls to `/api` is this:

```py
def performRequest(url, parameters, sslcontext):
    '''Perform request in a loop 10 times, because the central server’s instance might shut down unexpectedly during a request, especially longer running ones.'''

    success = False
    message = None
    data = urllib.parse.urlencode(parameters).encode('ascii')

    for i in range(10):
        try:
            response = urllib.request.urlopen(url, data, context=sslcontext)
            return True, response
        except:
            message = f'Response from {url} with parameters {parameters} after {i+1} tries: ' + traceback.format_exc().splitlines()[-1]

    return success, message
```

The weird part is that most of the time (exceptions apply) the calls identified correctly as POST show a low latency, and similar calls showing neither GET nor POST show a high latency.

The graph shows nicely that there are largely two categories of latencies happening: one line at around 100ms and another line at 800-1000ms. The higher ones are the ones not identified as GET or POST even tho the calls are made using the same methods (above Python method).

I measure the server's internal code execution speed in my flask-based server, and it's usually less than 100ms.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on?

Comment: did you try to use GCP profiler? https://cloud.google.com/profiler/docs/profiling-python

Comment: That's a very useful tool for analyzing my code, thank you. Didn't know about it. But it doesn't lead me to an answer, as it shows that the total code execution speed averages at 85ms, which is similar to what I thought.
I suspect the problem to be outside of my code, but don't know where to look.

Comment: On one hand I would suggest to add logging in `/api` to register the HTTP methods reaching the endpoint, this may shed some light on what kind of requests are causing this behavior as it might be related to an issue with the urllib library. On the other hand, to avoid the issue entirely you may explicitly construct a request object assigning the correct HTTP method yourself and then pass the request object to urlopen https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html